Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry Exercise 3.1.6
The exercise states:

Let $\pi : T\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of schemes. Supposing that $\pi : T\rightarrow S$ is an open or closed immersion, or that
$S=$Spec$A$, and $\pi $ is induced by a localisation $A\rightarrow F^{-1}A$ for a multiplicative subset $F\subset A $.


(a) Let $f,g : Z\rightarrow T$ be two morphisms of schemes such that $\pi \circ f = \pi \circ g$. Show that $f=g$.

Where I'm confused, is that it seems to me that if one were to set $Z=S$, and use the unique fibered product morphism $(f,g)$ such that $p \circ (f,g)=f$ and $q\circ (f,g)=g$; $p=q$ are the satisfactory projections $T\times_{S}T\rightarrow T$, and hence it would follow that in general, $f=g$, and therefore that an $S$-scheme $T$ only has one section. Where do I misunderstand?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Well, if $T \to S$ is an immersion then yeah there is at most one section of it, same thing if $T$ is a localization of an affine scheme $S$

I personally wouldn't advocate for solving this exercise via consideration of $T\times_S T$ but you absolutely can do that if you want to! And you’re right, in these situations there is at most one section of $\pi$ i.e. a map $S\to T$ so that $S\to T\to S$ is identity. One doesn’t have to exist, though.
Here's one way how:
If you want to phrase it in terms of $T\times_S T\to T$, this is saying all morphisms $Z\to T\times_S T$ (not morphisms of $S$-schemes, just genuine arbitrary scheme morphisms) factor through $\Delta_{T/S}:T\to T\times_S T$. In particular $1:T\times_S T\to T\times_S T$ factors through $\Delta_{T/S}$ and considering the left inverses $p,q$ to $\Delta_{T/S}$ we can conclude $p=q$ and that $\Delta_{T/S}$ is actually an isomorphism.
Thus, an equivalent statement (and this is very general, category-theoretic) is that $\Delta_{T/S}$ is an isomorphism when $T\to S$ is a closed or open immersion or a localisation of an affine scheme. Hopefully all these statements are quite clear; for localisations or closed immersions, taking $\Delta_{T/S}$ locally on the target boils the work down to understanding canonical isomorphisms $F^{-1}A\otimes_A F^{-1}A\cong F^{-1}A$ and $(A/J)\otimes_A(A/J)\cong A/J$.
As for the open immersion, you can cover $T\times_ST$ with many opens of type $\mathrm{Spec}(A_f\otimes_A A_f)$ and then likewise, taking $F=(1,f,f^2,f^3,\cdots)$ we see $A_f\otimes_A A_f\cong A_f$ via the map associated to $\Delta$.

wrt what I meant by "only has one section"; if $f=g$ were true for $f,g: S\rightarrow T$, it would follow that any two sections on the morphism $S\rightarrow T$ were equal.

An immersion $T \to T \sqcup T $ has no section (that doesnt change anything to the rest of your answer though) unless $T$ is empty.

@Ahr I thought it worked - it definitely does topologically - but maybe I need to think more

@FShirke if $T$ is an $S$-scheme defined by $\pi : T\rightarrow S$, then any two sections $f,g : S\rightarrow T$ would be such that $\pi \circ f=$Id$_{S}= \pi \circ g$

I think it's because you subconsciously interpret the section in the way that it exists  =)
A section of $T \to T\sqcup T$ is a map $T \to T\sqcup T$ such that $ T\sqcup T \to T \to T\sqcup T$ is the identity (not $ T \to T\sqcup T \to T$) and this clearly doesnt exist, even topologically or set theoretically

@Noah Yep, sorry. Since we were talking about immersions I was defaulting to viewing the inclusion as the map having the left inverse, rather than the other way around. But of course you’re right, your usage of ‘section’ is more appropriate here.
